# I am getting The method 'cast' was called on null while parsing json

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following json in my API response :

```
{
    "data": [{
        "orderid": "123",
        "item_names": [
            "item1",
            "item2",
            "item3",
            "item4"
        ]
    }]
}
```

and i have following model class in dart :

```
class OrderListResponse {
  List<OrderListItemModel> data;

  OrderListResponse({this.data});

  OrderListResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = new List<OrderListItemModel>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new OrderListItemModel.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class OrderListItemModel {
  String id;
  List<String> items;

  OrderListItemModel({this.id,
  this.items,

  });

  OrderListItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    items = json['item_names'].cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['item_names'] = this.items;
    return data;
  }
}
```

When I will get data in API it gives me an error The method 'cast' was called on null. I am not getting why it throws this error. Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you to use [this website](https://app.quicktype.io/) to convert your jsons

and so on, to fix you're code you need to change

```
  OrderListItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    items = json['item_names'].cast<String>();
  }
```

to this

```
   OrderListItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['orderid'];
    items = json["item_names"] == null? [] : List<String>.from(json["item_names"].map((x) => x))
}
```

Comment: Tried your code but it gives The method 'map' was called on null.

Comment: @deepak that's bc json["item_names"] is null, i updated the code try it agian

Comment: Works clearly for my issue, thank you @SajadAbdollahi

Answer (score 1):

You had a few mistakes in your code:

- You are trying to cast a `string` to an `array`.
- Your are trying to parse field `id` but the JSON field is `orderid`

Try this code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var js = '''{
    "data": [{
        "orderid": "123",
        "item_names": [
            "item1",
            "item2",
            "item3",
            "item4"
        ]
    }]
}''';
  
  var orders = OrderListResponse.fromJson(json.decode(js));
  
  for (var order in orders.data) {
    print(order.id);
    for (var item in order.items) {
      print(item);
    }
  }
}


class OrderListResponse {
  List<OrderListItemModel> data;

  OrderListResponse({this.data});

  OrderListResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = new List<OrderListItemModel>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new OrderListItemModel.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class OrderListItemModel {
  String id;
  List<String> items;

  OrderListItemModel({this.id,
  this.items,

  });

  OrderListItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['orderid'];
    items = List<String>.from(json["item_names"].map((x) => x));
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['orderid'] = this.id;
    data['item_names'] = this.items;
    return data;
  }
}
```